# php foreach next month dates

Tags: php, date, foreach

What I need is get listed next month days, every new day on new line.
Actually I want it look next:

```
date     | username1 | username2
_________|___________|__________
         |           |
Mon - 01 | user5     | user2
         |           |
Tue - 02 | user3     | user2

....
and so on
```

Later i will be collect these dates and usernames to and update sql table (same type, like example here).

I have this code:

```
$workdays = array();
$type = CAL_GREGORIAN;
$month = date('n'); // Month ID, 1 through to 12.
$year = date('Y'); // Year in 4 digit 2009 format.
$day_count = cal_days_in_month($type, $month, $year); // Get the amount of days
//loop through all days
for ($i = 1; $i <= $day_count; $i++) {
$date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$i; //format date
$workdays[] = $i;
```

and with foreach echo i get days 1, 2, 3 ... and so on correctly, everyone on new line. But if i place inside foreach this:

```
<?php foreach($workdays as $value['date']): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php if ($value['date'] != 'dd'){
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fi_FI.UTF-8');
    echo ucfirst(strftime("%a - %d", strtotime($value['date'])));
    } else {
    echo 'wrong';
    }?></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I get on every new line Mon - 01.

What is wrong (after that, that i newbie on php)?

Comment: Where is your full issued code? I can't to see any `foreach` around your `<td>`. Where you initialize your `$value`?

Comment: If we guess `$value['date']` is the fetched row...then you need to fetch all rows by `mysql_fetch_array()` and i think you did it once. So every time you are getting Mon - 01!

Comment: One moment, i edit post now.

Comment: @sjagr: [`cal_days_in_month()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) is not user-defined function...

Comment: So, you `$value['date']` contains consequence integers from `$i` instead of dates from `$date`... :(

Comment: and really? Is your foreach worked? It's first time I see `as $arr['key']` construction

Comment: vp_arth, do you have better idea to get listed next month dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
<?php

$day_count = date('t',strtotime('+1 month'));
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y');

if ($month == 12) { $month = 1; $year++; }

for($i = 1; $i<=$day_count; $i++) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.date('D',strtotime("$month/$i/$year")).' '.$i."</td>";
  echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This one works like i need. And again I learned a lot.